# aggregating the data in different columns based on condition in r

Tags: r

```
order_id customer_id extension_of quantity cost duration
1      123      srujan           NA        1  100       30
2      456        teja           NA        1  100       30
3      789      srujan          123        1  100       30
```

I have sample data which contains order information. What I need to do is summarize the data(sum of cost etc) if value of `order_id` and `extension_of columns` matches.

Comment: *"if value of order_id and extension_of columns matches"* But your sample data has zero rows with matching `order_id` and `extension_of`. Can you please clarify and include your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you want to add rows #1 and #3 as #1 is like the parent order and #3 is its extension. Here's one way you can do it (assuming `dft` is your data frame):

```
library(purrr)
dft$parent_id <- map2_dbl(dft$order_id, dft$extension_of, function(order_id, extension_of) if(is.na(extension_of)) order_id else extension_of)
aggregate(cost~parent_id, data=dft, FUN=sum)
```

This can *not* do recursion (i.e. an extension being extended itself), but it does sum up for one level.

If you need several levels, you can go for something like this:

```
library(purrr)
find_root <- function(order_id, extension_of){
  if(is.na(extension_of)){
    return(order_id)
  }else{
    parent_ext <- dft$extension_of[dft$order_id==extension_of]
    return(find_root(extension_of, parent_ext))
  }
}
dft$parent_id <- map2_dbl(dft$order_id, dft$extension_of, find_root)
aggregate(cost~parent_id, data=dft, FUN=sum) # same as before
```

(not it looks up the parent's parent, if necessary). One can certainly optimize for performance if really needed; the principle will stay the same, however.

Comment: what is the solution if extension order is again extended i,e order extended more than one level.. please help me out on this

Comment: added an alternative w/ recursion

Comment: Thank you so much sebastian. How to achieve parents' parent id value in another column. could you please throw some light on that as I am not getting any idea on how to do it.